# Tab-completing functions in Emacs outside of parentheses or quotes

Tags: completion

In Emacs version 25.1.1 (and probably other versions), tab completion not work for function names unless they are enclosed in parentheses or quoted.  For instance, after running emacs -Q, setting `tab-always-indent` to `'complete` and attempting to complete "seq-" after `(require 'seq)`, no completions are offered.  However, "(seq-" completes as one would expect.

Is there a way to complete function names outside of quotes?

Edit: this issue also occurs with normal functions and not just generic ones as pointed out in the comments.

Edit: If helm is used for completion, one approach is to use the following code:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook (lambda ()
                                  (setq-local completion-at-point-functions '(helm-lisp-completion-at-point))))
```

Comment: Assuming you're in `emacs-lisp-mode` you should take a look at `elisp-completion-at-point` that explicitly checks for "function position" with `(eq (char-before beg) ?\()`. A `(seq-` TAB (or a `'seq-`) will therefore complete all `seq` functions as expected.

Comment: In 26.0.50.2, I start with `emacs -Q`, then do `M-x emacs-lisp-mode`, and `(require 'seq) (setq tab-always-indent 'complete)` and then a TAB does show completions. Can you try in emacs -Q? Do you get completions for other libraries? What do you mean by "generic"?

Comment: Works for me in 25.1 as well.

Comment: @matbuerger That's interesting.  But it only works when there is a paren before or after "seq-".

Comment: @ unhammer I did use -Q.  Generic means a Common Lisp style generic function as defined with cl-defgeneric.

Comment: Are you sure that you have loaded `seq`? If it wasn't loaded, functions defined in it aren't loaded and they don't exist to emacs. You can use <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> after a sexp to evaluate it, and doing so on `(require 'seq)` should fix your problem.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa I'm sure.

Comment: 'But it only works when there is a paren before "seq-"' - that's expected, since there are no variables whose name starts with `seq-`.

Comment: @npostavs It's not a variable, but it is fboundp so I would expect it to work.  There are plenty of cases where it is useful to have a symbol that is fboundp outside of the function position.

Comment: Functions names are given as completion candidates also following `'` as well. Anyway, this has nothing to do with generic functions in particular. See also [Emacs Bug#19854 - Document new behaviour of elisp at point completion wrt funcs vs vars](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19854#26).